# Why is there no Delete Profile link anymore?

Tags: support, user-accounts, profile-page

[image]

Under "Edit Profile" should've been an option for leaving the community.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only self-delete your profile if the profile has **never voted** and has **posted at most once** in the history of the account. If this is not true, the Delete Profile link will not be shown.

To delete a profile which does not meet this criteria, use the [contact us](https://apple.stackexchange.com/contact) link and choose ‘I need to delete my user profile’.

Practically, it's simpler to just anonymize your profile if that's what you want - deletion just automates the anonymization of your posts and profile. If you're asking about linking accounts - that's a different path: http://stackexchange.com/users/218740/bmike?tab=accounts